# Override hardcoded spring properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath

I have the following problem. I have a jar archive with a spring application inside (pure spring with xml configuration, without spring-boot). Someone decided to move some properties to external file. Unfortunately, the path is hardcoded in xml context file, so it looks like this:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:hardcoded/path/props.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Both xml context file and property file are inside the archive. The application works fine, however, I need to change (override) some properties from the hardcoded file. Unfortunately, I can't modify or compile new jar. I tried adding files with overriden properties to the classpath (with the same name) and also passing some properties as jvm args, but it didn't work. How can I replace/override this file from classpath without modifying the original java archive?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html).

> Property resource configurer that overrides bean property values in an
>   application context definition. It pushes values from a properties
>   file into bean definitions.

That should allow you to "push" your own values on top of the prior-loaded set.